# Prove that linear operator T is the projection Operator

Tags: linear-transformations, projection

I got question prove or disprove

> Let be $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ linear oprator and let be $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ hyperplane.
>
> If known that $Image(T)=U$ and also that for every $u\in U$, $T(u)=u$.
>
> So $T$ is projection operator on $U$.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the projection operator is defined as $T^2=T$.

Consider $v\in \mathbb R^n$. Can you think of a way, why $T^2v=Tv$ holds? It is maybe easier to see if you write
$$
T^2v=Tv \Leftrightarrow T(T(v)) = T(v).
$$
You don't to it normally this way, but let us make it one step more obvious:

We define $w=Tv$. Now we get
$$
 T(T(v))=T(v) \Leftrightarrow T(w)=w.
$$
Consider, that $w$ is an element of the image of $T$.
And that this holds, is writen in your condition.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you give me an example maybe ?

Comment: I rewrote it a bit. But the step to see, why $T^2=T$ holds if $T$ is the identity on its image, which is a hyperplane, is a very small one... It isn't even worth to be called a proof.